# R Shiny user directory reactive output

Tags: r, shiny

I was hoping someone could help me figure out how to make a reactive text display of the working directory that the user chooses. Essentially I would just like a blank box saying "No working directory chosen". Once they choose a working directory using the UI, I would like the box to update with the directory path.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Qualtrics Automation"),
  textInput("sfnumber", "Enter SF Number", value = "test"),
  shinyDirButton('folder', 'Select a folder', 'Please select a folder', FALSE),
  actionButton("runScript", "Run")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    shinyDirChoose(input, 'folder', 
                   roots = c(wd = paste0('C:/Users/',Sys.info()[["user"]],"/clientfolder"),
                   filetypes=c('', 'txt')))
    
  })
  
  
  mylist <- reactiveVal() # we will store the inputs in a reactive list

  observe({ # create the list
    mylist(list(
      sfnumber = input$sfnumber,
      workdir = input$folder))
  })
  

  observeEvent(input$runScript, { # "runScript" is an action button
    source("source_script2.R", local = list2env(mylist()), echo = T)
  })
  
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
  
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is an image I created of what I would like it to look like:

[image]

```
> version
               _                                
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          2.2                              
year           2022                             
month          10                               
day            31                               
svn rev        83211                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
nickname       Innocent and Trusting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its needed to explicit implement reactivity in this case, since
`renderPrint` can be reactive. Validate if there is an `input$folder` and then render the unlisted `input$folder$path` with `verbatimTextOutput` to generate a text field in the UI.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyDirButton('folder', 'Select a folder', 'Please select a folder', FALSE),
  verbatimTextOutput("current")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    shinyDirChoose(input, 'folder', 
                   roots = c(wd = paste0('C:/Users/',Sys.info()[["user"]],"/clientfolder"),
                             filetypes=c('', 'txt')))
  output$current <- renderPrint({
    validate(
      need(input$folder, "No working directory chosen"),
      need(is.vector(input$folder) , "")  # To silcence the $ Error

    )
    paste(unlist(input$folder$path),collapse = "/")
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I removed some code that is not related to the problem.

Comment: I get: Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors when using this. Although it appears as a list if I save the variable to my environment, shiny is treating it as a vector for some reason.

Comment: The error should disappear once you selected the folder. because the input$folder$path  list is  empty during the selection process

Comment: i edited     need(is.vector(input$folder) , "") to supress the error

Comment: how would I make the path a variable for my script I source to use?